# Passing a character for prompt control

Tags: c

So I was given this function to read options to perform. I understand the execution of the prompts but I am having trouble passing the 'c' back to the program. I figure it has something to do with pointers I have yet to grasp.

```
   int nextCommand(int *x, int *y)
        {
            char c;
            while(1){
                scanf("%c", &c);
                if (c == 's' || c == 'p') break;
                if (c == 'f' || c == 'F') {scanf("%d", x); break;}
                if (c == 'u') {scanf("%d", x); scanf("%d", y); break;}
            }
            return c;
        }
```

To actually describe my question. When I call this function the program is at a standstill. I try to enter one of the appropriate commands (i.e. s or p) and the program ends. Sorry I put this question up at the end of a long night.

Comment: It should work as-is. The function returns either `s`, `p`, `f`, `F`, or `u`. Maybe you need to describe your question better.

Comment: What is the actual question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the use of scanf of x and y?
the program seems to be correct. What is the problem you are encountering? can you give details of what problem are you facing?

Comment: x and y are used as addt'l parameters for the functions I am using in the program. like the commands s, p do not need any parameters for their functions.

Comment: ya but whatever u send to this function, its irrelevant to what function does. THe output of function has no relation with function parameters. ok fine. this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The function simply returns a char (i.e. 1 byte of data on many platforms, but not all) to whoever called it.

So for example in your main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a = 0, b =0;
    char result;

    result = nextCommand(&a, &b);

    /* at this point result will contain the single character 's', or 'u', or... etc. */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a char is 1 byte by definition (on all platforms)